# Why can't I modify Javascript in this code using Chrome's "Inspect Element"?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, xss

```
<html>
<script>
function redir(item){
    window.location = "http://www.google.com/search?q="+item;
}
</script>

<body>
    <input type="text" onblur="redir(this.value)">
</body>
</html>
```

I am facing 2 issues with this code:

1) When I modify the Javascript to do a different task, say,

```
alert('Hello');
```

it does not get reflected as it still redirects to www.google.com.

2) When I modify the onblur attribute of the text field, I'm getting different results on Chrome and Firefox.

*Firefox: It modifies the onblur attribute correctly and works as expected.*

*Chrome: It does modify the onblur attribute, but somehow triggers both the new code AND the original code.*

Is it just a bug in chrome or am I missing knowledge of some known feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript code in a `<script>` tag is parsed when the page is loaded and it is put into force in the underlying script engine.  Modifying it after you're already viewing the page is too late to effect a change in the operating Javascript of the page.  It isn't reparsed just because you edited it.

Javascript code in an HTML attribute is a string and is not parsed until the event occurs at which time, it is evaluated with something like `eval()`.  So, if you change it with Inspect Element and THEN the event occurs, the newly changed code string will be evaluated from scratch each time the event occurs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This cleared all the doubts :)